# Set array value to Dropdown using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I am newbie to Angularjs. Here is my scenario.

I have an array of

`numbers = ['1','2','3'];`

And also have a

`<select id="fileNumber" ng-model="files"></select>`

How Can I add the values of array to the dropdown list `fileNumber`

I tried,

`ng-options="numbers"`

Can anyone say how to include array value to dropdown list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an example for working with select and adding values to array:

**Update:**

```
  <select ng-model='selectedNumber'  ng-options='number for number in numbers'></select>
<button ng-click="add()">add</button>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/MTfRD/643/

Answer (score 4):

Read and follow [ng-select directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect%E2%80%8E)

Comment: +1. @Vinod, just read the docs once and you will know how to do this.

Comment: The moment I clicked the link,

 "The page you requested does not exist. Perhaps you were looking for something else..."